# Django | Equivalente de {% url 'test_app:test' 'historia' %} en una view

Tags: django

Cuando hago un url con argumento en un template funciona perfecto, pero sucede que cuando quiero hacer ese url dentro de una view con un return redirect, parece que el argumento no llega. ¿Cómo se debería hacer? Gracias.

**Template.html** (Aquí funciona perfecto)

```
{% url 'test_app:test' 'historia' %}
```

**Views.py:** (No funciona. Se abre el template pero sin contenido ya que el argumento no llegó)

```
return(redirect(reverse('test_app:test'),questionModality='historia'))
```

**Urls.py:**

```
app_name = 'test_app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('test/<str:questionModality>/',
        views.testFilterByModalityAndByUserView.as_view(),
        name='test',
    )
]
```

Answer (score 0):

En redirigir desde dentro de la view a una url con argumentos, funciona de la siguiente manera utilizando eso sí las HttpResponseRedirect. Funciona perfecto.

Views.py

```
....
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('test_app:test', kwargs={'questionModality': 'Ciencias'}))
```